# Confused about exception handling in async (Kotlin coroutines)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am studying exception handling mechanism in coroutines, and the difference in behaviour w.r.t different coroutine builders.

With launch, the exception is thrown, and gets caught as per the code (i.e. in try-catch or coroutine exception handler or thread's uncaught exception handler if there's nothing to catch it)

With async, the exception is encapsulated in the deferred object, and not thrown until we call 'await' on it.

For the following code however:

```kotlin
    fun main() {
        val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { coroutineContext, throwable ->
            println("Caught exception $throwable in CoroutineExceptionHandler")
        }
        val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + exceptionHandler);

        val deferred = scope.async {
            functionThatThrows()
        }

        scope.launch {
           deferred.await()
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    private fun functionThatThrows() {
        throw RuntimeException("");
    }
```

The exception here, should have been thrown (since deferred.await() is being called), and caught inside the exception handler, but it does not and nothing is printed.
The interesting thing, is *if I add a delay statement in the async block (before the call to functionThatThrows(), exception is thrown and caught inside the exception handler.*

How is delay affecting the exception handling mechanism here? I fail to understand this.

**PS: As an observation from the comment below, this works fine in Kotlin playground, but behaviour is different in Android Studio (at-least on my local machine)**

Comment: Tried your code in [kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/Sy6rNre0q), which throws correctly.

Comment: @RickyMo That's correct, but now I am confused why the behaviour is different in Android Studio. Can you try running it locally on Studio, and let me know the behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

There is a race condition in your example. If the body of `async()` is executed before getting to `launch()`, then the exception has been already thrown and the whole `scope` is considered inactive. Then `launch()` has no effect.

Even if it reaches `await()` and then the exception is thrown, at this moment the coroutine machinery starts executing two separate exception handling mechanisms. One is passing the exception through the `deferred`, another is cancelling all coroutines in the `scope`. First will throw from `await()`, the second won't (technically, it will also throw, but a special `CancellationException` which is not considered a failure). I'm not sure if coroutines provide guarantees on what should happen first in such a case.

> With async, the exception is encapsulated in the deferred object, and not thrown until we call 'await' on it.

Well, this is not entirely true. Exception thrown in `async {}` still propagates according to the structured concurrency concept. We can see this with this simple example:

```kotlin
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {
    async {
        error("")
    }

    delay(1000)
    println("Unreachable")
}
```

Even if we don't at all use the result of `async()`, it still stops our parent coroutine from continuing. This is also true while using a coroutine scope:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(EmptyCoroutineContext)

    println(scope.isActive) // true

    scope.async {
        delay(100)
        error("")
    }

    println(scope.isActive) // true
    Thread.sleep(500)
    println(scope.isActive) // false
}
```

After throwing the exception, `scope` is no longer active and it doesn't execute coroutines anymore.

I assume the confusion comes from this fragment in the documentation:

> Coroutine builders come in two flavors: propagating exceptions automatically (launch and actor) or exposing them to users (async and produce). When these builders are used to create a root coroutine, that is not a child of another coroutine, the former builders treat exceptions as uncaught exceptions, similar to Java's Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler, while the latter are relying on the user to consume the final exception, for example via await or receive (produce and receive are covered in Channels section).

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exception-handling.html#exception-propagation

I can't fully explain its meaning in relation to examples provided above, it is a little confusing to me as well. I think this fragment of documentation focuses strictly on how to handle exceptions that propagated to the very top of a coroutine tree, for example to show them to the user. Even if we consume the exception from `await()` or by using the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, that doesn't mean this exception is considered to be handled from the perspective of the structured concurrency. It still fails the whole scope and makes it unusable.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I tried with Thread.sleep(10) and it works as expected in that case. However, I was following a tutorial which suggested that the exception is encapsulated in 'deferred' object and not thrown until 'await' is called. In case it's not thrown, how will the scope cancel out? Or maybe I am not understanding it correctly.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Actually, it took more text to explain this part than the original answer ;-)

Comment: Why do you say we almost never work with root coroutines? Every time we call `scope.launch` or `scope.async`, we are working with a root coroutine, and it's important to know what to expect with uncaught exceptions behavior in these two situations. Notably, if you use `scope.async` and never await it, you could have a failure occurring with nothing in the log, which would make debugging difficult.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Hmm, you are correct. If I think about it, it is a little confusing to me as well. Technically speaking coroutines started with `scope.launch()` are not root coroutines, they have a parent job stored in the scope. But you are correct, they are handled as root coroutines from the perspective of the doc mentioned above. So they are roots, but they can cancel their parents and/or siblings. Sounds a little self-contradicting. Now I totally understand why it may confuse people. I'm not sure what to do with my answer :-D

Comment: If you think of "root" as a coroutine started from a CoroutineScope, then it makes sense. I've never thought of the parent Job of a CoroutineScope as a coroutine since it doesn't run coroutine code.

Comment: Yes, but then how to explain the case from the question? Why the code block inside `launch()` didn't execute? `async()` is a root coroutine and according to docs their exceptions are handled by the consumer (`await()`). Which is clearly not the case here, because `launch()` was entirely ignored due to an exception inside `async()`. I mean, I understand what's happening here from the technical perspective, but it's hard to explain in referring to existing docs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I entirely rewritten the answer. To be honest, I'm not exactly sure if this is 100% correct.